# Array of Classes NullPointerException

Tags: java

This is `Element` class:

```
public class Element {

    private String elementName;
    private int atomicNumber;
    private String Symbol;
    private double atomicWeight;

    public Element()
    {

    }

    public String getElementName()
    {
        return elementName;
    }
    public int getAtomicNumber()
    {
        return atomicNumber;
    }
    public String getSymbol()
    {
        return Symbol;
    }
    public double getAtomicWeight()
    {
        return atomicWeight;
    }
    public void setElementName(String elementName)
    {
        this.elementName = elementName;
    }
    public void setAtomicNumber(int atomicNumber)
    {
        this.atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
    }
    public void setSymbol(String Symbol)
    {
        this.Symbol = Symbol;
    }
    public void setAtomicWeight(double atomicWeight)
    {
        this.atomicWeight = atomicWeight;
    }

}
```

I am trying to make an `Array` of this class, this is my `mainU.java` class:

```
public class mainU {

    public static void main(String[] args){     

            Element[] element = new Element[103];

        element[0].setElementName("H");
        String s = element[0].getElementName();

        System.out.println(s);

}
```

The problem is that i'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mainU.main(mainU.java:14)
```

Anyone can tell me the reason i'm getting such an error?
I made my program as simple as possible in order for you to be able to help me.

Comment: you should learn how to use a debugger (in case you already don't know) - a debuggers would have helped you solve this many times quicker than writing this question.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is in the part:

```
Element[] element = new Element[103];
element[0].setElementName("H");
```

Your accessing the first element without creating it before that. you create the array but it doesnt containt automatically new objects of the type used, you have to declare these explicitly, for example:

```
element[0] = new element();
```

And then you can use the object.

Answer (score 1):

Creating new object arrays will yield arrays filled with `null`. If you need to have objects, you will have to iterate over the array after its creation and populate it with new instances.

Comment: Yes, but i am not accessing a NULL object, i am accessing element[0] which I have set for it an element name using the method `setElementName`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create objects. You just created array of object references.

```
Element[] element = new Element[103];
for(int i=0; i<103; i++) {
   element[i] = new Element();
}
```

As your element is object (arrays are object) and it is stored on heap. All Element object references are initialized to null value. Due to which you are getting `NPE`s.

```
Element[] element = new Element[103];
element[0].setElementName("H");  // element[0] is null
```

Answer (score 1):

you have only initialized the Element Array but never initialized its elements,

```
        Element[] element = new Element[103];
    element[0].setElementName("H");// this cause NPE as element[0] is null
```

You need to initialize the elements like below:

```
      Element[] element = new Element[103];
       element[0] = new Element();
      element[0].setElementName("H");
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring an array like initialises the array object, but not the elements of the array. You need to create an Element object at each index of the array.

```
element[0] = new Element();
element[0].setElementName("H");
```

Comment: ahhh!! OK i understand now! i'll give it a try! but should the declaration stay `Element[] element = new Element[103]` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array of objects all it's elements are initialized to `null`. You simply have to create a new `Element` object and add it to the array like this:

```
Element[] elems = new Element[100];
elems[0] = new Element();
elem[0].setElementName("asdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized `element[0]` . You need to initialize it first, in fact every array element if you intent to use them.

```
element[0]=new Element();
```

or you can initialize all of them using loop

```
  for(int i=0;i<element.length;i++)
  {
    element[i]=new Element();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Between those two lines

```
 Element[] element = new Element[103];
 element[0].setElementName("H");
```

you need to create `element[0]`, that is to build a new instance of `Element`. In your code `element[0]` is null, hence the `NullPointerException` when you call `setElementName`.