# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, debugging, nullpointerexception

I can't believe I'm having so much trouble on something so trivial.

For whatever reason, these lines of code are causing a `nullpointerexception`

```
Card[] arr = new Card[2];
System.out.print(arr[0].val + "\n"); //this is the line throwing the error
```

Card is defined as

```
public class Card {
    public int val;
    public char suit;
}
```

Compilation is successful, I made sure it's referencing the right class. I feel like I'm overlooking some small detail.

I also noticed that

```
Card a = new Card();
Card b = new Card();
Card[] arr = {a, b};
System.out.print(arr[0].val + "\n");
```

works perfectly fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array of Classes NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258058/array-of-classes-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you declare `Card[] arr = new Card[2];`, every reference inside of your array is `null`.  You **must** instantiate a new `Card()` in each spot before you attempt to call methods on it.

This is why your second approach works - you've got two new instances of a `Card`, and you're populating them inside of the array *before* you call any methods on it.

Comment: I had a fundamental misunderstanding as to what the "new" operator on arrays was actually supposed to be doing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have created *space* for your array in memory (you've "initialized" it), but you've not put anything *in* it.

Try something like

```
arr[0] = new Card();

//NOW there's something in arr[0];

System.out.println(arr[0]);
```

That's why it works in the final code snippet, because this is exactly what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

```
Card[] arr = new Card[2];
```

arr reference contains Array object with length 2. Also the above statement states that each object in the array is of class type Card. By default, no objects are created by the above statement and all the indexes in the array will have null references.

```
arr[0] = null;
arr[1] = null;
```

---

arr[0] = new Card();

Card Object is created and its reference is arr[0] i.e. 1st index of array

---

Base rule: Any array will be created with its default value in its index positions.

A primitive array will have default value of that primitive type, for example int[] will have 0, boolean[] has false

An Object array is created consisting references to null since Object default value is null. The number of references created is equal to the length provided in its initialization.

arr[0] itself is not an object. arr[0] is a reference to an object which should be created explicitly in Java.

Answer (score 0):

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3),

> Array components are unnamed variables that are *created* and *initialized* to **default** values ([§4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)) whenever a new object that is an array is created...

Your object array is declared in first case `Card[] arr = new Card[2];` and is initialized with `null`. Since the array is not populated with Card type objects, it is actually pointing to default `null` value and when you try to print it, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

In the second case `Card[] arr = {a, b};` you have created `new` Card type objects and populated the array with those objects and when you try to print it, the value is returned and displayed.

Comment: Please explain the negative vote. I will make changes if something isn't right.